# Concat array via checkboxes in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to coding and trying to learn React. I'm trying to make a flashcard app to learn Japanese. The idea is that you have a series of checkboxes so you can choose Hiragana or Katakana and what 'columns' of Japanese script you want to practice. Here's what I have right now:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./japanesescript.js";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      allHiraganaChecked: false,
      allKatakanaChecked: false,
      hiraganaList: [
        { id: "cbhvowels", name: "vowels", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbhk", name: "K", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbhs", name: "S", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbht", name: "T", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbhn", name: "N", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbhh", name: "H", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbhm", name: "M", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbhy", name: "Y", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbhr", name: "R", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbhw", name: "W", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbhmisc", name: "n/m", isChecked: false },
      ],
      katakanaList: [
        { id: "cbkvowels", name: "vowels", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbkk", name: "K", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbks", name: "S", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbkt", name: "T", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbkn", name: "N", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbkh", name: "H", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbkm", name: "M", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbky", name: "Y", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbkr", name: "R", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbkw", name: "W", isChecked: false },
        { id: "cbkmisc", name: "n/m", isChecked: false },
      ],
      flashList: [],
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className="checkbox-container">
        <label>Hiragana</label>
        {this.checkAllHirigana()}
        <br />
        <label>Katakana</label>
        {this.checkAllKatakana()}
      </div>
    );
  }

  checkAllHirigana = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="checkAllHiragana"
          checked={this.state.allHiraganaChecked}
          onChange={this.handleHiraganaChange}
        />
        Check all
        <br />
        {this.renderHiriganaList()}
      </div>
    );
  };

  checkAllKatakana = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          name="checkAllKatakana"
          checked={this.state.allKatakanaChecked}
          onChange={this.handleKatakanaChange}
        />
        Check all
        <br />
        {this.renderKatakanaList()}
      </div>
    );
  };

  renderHiriganaList = () => {
    return this.state.hiraganaList.map((item) => (
      <div>
        <input
          key={item.id}
          // id={item.id}
          type="checkbox"
          name={item.name}
          value={item.name}
          checked={item.isChecked}
          onChange={this.handleHiraganaChange}
        />
        <label>{item.name}</label>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  renderKatakanaList = () => {
    return this.state.katakanaList.map((item) => (
      <div>
        <input
          key={item.id}
          // id={item.id}
          type="checkbox"
          name={item.name}
          value={item.name}
          checked={item.isChecked}
          onChange={this.handleKatakanaChange}
        />
        <label>{item.name}</label>
      </div>
    ));
  };

  handleHiraganaChange = (e) => {
    let itemName = e.target.name;
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let { hiraganaList, allHiraganaChecked } = prevState;
      if (itemName === "checkAllHiragana") {
        allHiraganaChecked = checked;
        hiraganaList = hiraganaList.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          isChecked: checked,
        }));
      } else {
        hiraganaList = hiraganaList.map((item) =>
          item.name === itemName ? { ...item, isChecked: checked } : item
        );
        allHiraganaChecked = hiraganaList.every((item) => item.isChecked);
      }
      return { hiraganaList, allHiraganaChecked };
    });
  };

  handleKatakanaChange = (e) => {
    let itemName = e.target.name;
    let checked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      let { katakanaList, allKatakanaChecked } = prevState;
      if (itemName === "checkAllKatakana") {
        allKatakanaChecked = checked;
        katakanaList = katakanaList.map((item) => ({
          ...item,
          isChecked: checked,
        }));
      } else {
        katakanaList = katakanaList.map((item) =>
          item.name === itemName ? { ...item, isChecked: checked } : item
        );
        allKatakanaChecked = katakanaList.every((item) => item.isChecked);
      }
      return { katakanaList, allKatakanaChecked };
    });
  };

  updateStateList(e, value) {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      //append to array
      this.setState({
        flashList: this.state.flashList.concat([value]),
      });
    } else {
      //remove from array
      this.setState({
        flashList: this.state.flashList.filter(function (val) {
          return val !== value;
        }),
      });
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

1. I'm trying to get the checkboxes to add to the array 'flashList' when they're checked so that the app will randomly select a Japanese character in the concated (concacted?) array. I had everything in a separate component js file but thought maybe it would be better to have it on same file and now nothing gets added at all
2. The check all feature doesn't add anything to the array at all. When I try to add the onClick function to them, it doesn't accept 'item'
3. I know it's not very DRY, hoping to get it working and then reduce the code after

Answer (score 0):

You already have the 'state' of the 'checkeds' in the 'hiraganaList'
To check which ones are 'checkeds' you don't need the 'flashList' just scroll through the list and check the 'isChecked' item.

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    console.log(
      this.state.katakanaList.filter((item) => item.isChecked)
    );
  }}
>
  get all
</button>
```